# using System.Drawing.Imaging; Imaging does not exist in the System.Drawing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, exif

I am attempting to pull metadata from photos in a .Net Core App by using this library:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27242/ExifTagCollection-An-EXIF-metadata-extraction-libr

However while implementing the ExifTagCollection class I am getting the Error listed in the title.

[image]

I have successfully referenced System.Drawing but it is not recognizing its drawing extension. Any help would be great. Also open to suggestions for other libraries to accomplish my goal. Thx

Comment: Whits platform do you use?

Comment: Thx for response. Not sure what you mean I am trying to integrate with a web application. Think I may be missing a System.Windows.Forms reference, checking now....

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!
 - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : _Classes within the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions._

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I added the tag

Comment: Install the CoreCompat nuget package.

Comment: john Would that make this library compatible with asp.net core?

Comment: @RyeGuy I'm not 100% sure for your issue, but CoreCompat provides System.Drawing functionality in .NET Core. I'm using it in production code deployed on Linux and it works great. I've never tried extracting Exif information, however. Just basic GDI tasks.

https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat

This suggests it might work?: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the site of [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see:

*"Classes within the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions."*

You are creating a web application with ASP.net so this class isn't supported for your project

Comment: Thx for the answer. Going to have to find a new library to pull metadata from photos that works with ASP.NET Core MVC. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not |:

Comment: Your best bet is probably ImageSharp - https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp. However it hasn't reached a stable release yet.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for System.Drawing-related functionality on .NET Core, you should be able to use [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview1-25718-03).

It provides the System.Drawing API on .NET Core and works on Windows, Linux and macOS.

If you're on Linux and macOS, you'll need to install libgdiplus for this to work. To install libgdiplus on macOS, run `brew install mono-libgdiplus`; on Linux you should be able to install the `libgdiplus` package using your package manager. This deployment will hopefully get easier in the future.

It's currently in preview on NuGet as the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview1-25718-03) package.

Long term, you may want to consider migrating to other libraries such as ImageSharp.

Answer (score 2):

As @TimonPost says, you cannot use that namespace from ASP.NET, because it relies on there being an interactive session (which is why it also won't work from a Windows Service).

If you just want an easy way to access metadata from images that works in ASP.NET Core, check out my *MetadataExtractor* library.

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Comment: This library looks great Drew! Unfortunately if I tried installing it in the Package Manager Console and I get an error say 'Metadata extractor is not compatible with .netcoreapp1.1'

Comment: @RyeGuy, apologies, I should have said to use the prerelease of v2 (it's an option to the package manager). It'll be released soon, and is very stable. I am holding off because I might add one or two more features to the proper 2.0 release.