# How to save image from IFormFile

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core, file-upload, iformfile

I have *IFormFile* in my code and I want to save image from this to my PC. How can I do It?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I tryed use this code, but I think it is old code, so it is not work

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you know the format of image e.g. Jpeg):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
returnImage.Save(@"c:/your/desired/path/here/name.jpeg");
```

If you don't know image format, the code below helps you to save it in your desired format (Bmp, Tiff, Jpeg, Png, Gif, ...):

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;//add this with rest of usings

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
returnImage.Save(@"c:/your/desired/path/here/name.png", ImageFormat.Png);//in this example the format would be png
```

Comment: What type should be Image? My VS tells that 'System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image', but there is not method FromStream()

Comment: I have edited my answer to also reflect for times you don't know image type.

Comment: I tryed it. It is not work.
I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017938/13122668

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. This is code that I use:

```
    using FreeImageAPI;                   
var bytes = person.Image.GetBytes();


MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes.Result);

var b = FreeImageBitmap.FromStream(ms);
    b.Save("23",FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG);
```